# AngularJs re-size/adjust two div's accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've two div covering whole page 50% each and on lower div click i want it to cover full screen and come back on click again example

[JQuery equivalent](http://jsfiddle.net/2rxRx/17/)

```
    $('.wrapper div.green').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('go')
    if($(this).hasClass('go')){
      $(this).animate({'height':'100%'},{
          duration:200,
          step:function(gox){
              var height = gox < 100 ? (100 - gox) / 1 : 0;
              $(this).siblings().css('height', height + "%"); 
              }
          })
    }else{
        $('.wrapper div').animate({'height':'50.00%'},200)
    }
});
```

Now I want this in AngularJS and being new to it I've problems, so looking for some guidance to move in right direction. So far what I've tried

[AngularJs Attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/UvP54/182/)

All i want is a similar functionality as of JQuery.

Comment: Please don't place your links in code blocks to get around SO restrictions, they are there for a reason.

Comment: For some reason it's not letting me do it. You're welcome to edit it.

Comment: Actually, this should be handled with CSS. Edit : ok, I understood the question.

Comment: Just just have to toggle a class on the second div, on click.

Comment: @UmarIqbal, edited your question, should be updated my mods soon. You couldn't create links because links to JsFiddle have to be accompanied by code - you should have seen a clear error message about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on your first example - http://jsfiddle.net/nz2vunLs/2/

It uses CSS transistions and the angular directives [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick). I guess it's not the cleanest solution but it works.

**html**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller" class="wrapper">
    <div ng-class="{min: greenFullscreen}" class="blue animation"></div>
    <div ng-class="{max: greenFullscreen}" ng-click="toggleGreen()" class="green animation"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.greenFullscreen = false;

    $scope.toggleGreen = function() {
        $scope.greenFullscreen = !$scope.greenFullscreen;
    }
}
```

**Additional CSS**

```
.green.max {
    height: 100%;
}

.blue.min {
    height: 0%;
}

.animation {
    -webkit-transition: height 200ms;  
    -moz-transition: height 200ms;  
    -o-transition: height 200ms;  
    transition: height 200ms;
}
```